# iOS - Add ToggleSwitch on right-side of TableRow programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Currently I am adding an icon to the right-side of one row and toggle the light on selection of that specific row.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];
    ...
    ...
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if(row == 3)
    {
        //Draw bulb in row
        cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bulb-on.png"]];
            //Instead of image, draw toggle-switch here
    }
    else
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
```

How can I, instead of that image, draw a usable toggle-switch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Property accessoryView is just a usual UIView, so you can add any subviews to it:

```
UISwitch *toggleSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
cell.accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:toggleSwitch.frame];
[cell.accessoryView addSubview:toggleSwitch];
```

P.S. Don't forget to release allocated objects!